# .Net IdentityUser and Bearer Token

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have a webapi 2.0 that implements **bearer token**.

In this moment I have two user tables that are not related **AspNetUsers** and **anUser** (my custom table).

I need to reference the two tables with the **idUser** field present in **anUser** table.

I know that I have to customize **IdentityUser** implementing **ApplicationUser** but in my solution this ApplicationUser is not present so I don't know how to start to customize It.

What I need to do is reference the two tables and return the information from anUser Table each time the user to the login and the token is sent...

What are the steps that I have to do?
And how to check which version of Identity the webapi is implementing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found all the answer in this post:

http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/

Ciao